# Item tooltips after filtering source data

Tags: javascript, filtering, d3.js, tooltip

Rapidly getting familiar with D3.js.  One item I've noticed is that if I have a series of circles (I.e., a scatter plot) and I append tooltips to them derived from their source data, there seems to be a problem with updating those tooltips when I filter the data and redraw the circles.
Here's a portion of the code that gets called upon filtering the data.  Note that the filter is called from a mouse over in a different but correlated graph:

```
circs = itemCircles.selectAll('circle')
    .data(filteredData)
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return scatY(d.sim_fnl_occ); } )
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return scatX(d.sim_curr_occ); } )
    .attr('r', 5)
    ;

circs.enter().append('circle')
    .data(filteredData)
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return scatY(d.sim_fnl_occ); } )
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return scatX(d.sim_curr_occ); } )
    .attr('r', 5)
    ;

circs.append("svg:title")
    .text(function(d) { console.log(d.sim_curr_occ); // looking good!
    return d.sim_curr_occ });// looking bad:(
```

To the console gets written the correct values for the newly subsetted data; but the tooltips the,selves have incorrect data. In fact, it looks like the newly drawn circles retain the original tooltips. I should point out the circles get drawn appropriately, it's only the tooltips via the svg:title that are incorrect. 
Any guidance on wha I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the title on `enter()` instead of just appending it to the `circs`.

```
circs.enter().append('circle')
.data(filteredData)
.attr("cy", function (d) { return scatY(d.sim_fnl_occ); } )
.attr("cx", function (d) { return scatX(d.sim_curr_occ); } )
.attr('r', 5)
.append("svg:title")
.text(function(d) { 
  console.log(d.sim_curr_occ);
  return d.sim_curr_occ })
;
```

Comment: Thank you.  That tip coupled with another minor tweak got me what I needed.